# Difference between tf.random_normal() and tf.random_normal_initializer()

Tags: tensorflow, random

I'm learning Tensorflow these days.
When using random variables, I noticed there are two different versions. One is the API such as `tf.random_normal()` and the others are APIs like `tf.random_normal_initialize()`. I think those two are doing exactly the same things. The following is an example.

```
random_normal = tf.random_normal_initializer(0.0, 1.0, seed=0)
a = random_normal([10])
b = tf.random_normal([10], 0.0, 1.0)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    print (sess.run(a))
    print (sess.run(b))
```

I have two questions.

Q1. If these two are doing exactly the same thing,  why did they make duplicate APIs?

Q2. I assume that class names in Tensorflow start with an upper case letter such as `tf.Variable`, and "op" starts with lower cases. Then why `tf.random_normal_initializer` starts with a lower case letter while it is actually a class not an op.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you have a look at the respective implementations? The initializer (defined [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.8/tensorflow/python/ops/init_ops.py)) is a class that internally calls `tf.random_normal()`, which is just an operation (defined [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.8/tensorflow/python/ops/random_ops.py)). The attributes of the class instance for example can be exported for further use whereas the params of the op can not.

Concerning your second question: Your assumption is right. But the used name is just an alias. In the corresponding file is written

```
@tf_export("keras.initializers.RandomNormal", "initializers.random_normal",
       "random_normal_initializer")
class RandomNormal(Initializer):
  """Initializer that generates tensors with a normal distribution.
```

You can see that this is consistent with the naming convention.

Hope this helps.